# PHP: <img> not showing in wordpress template

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

I have seen many versions of this problem and went through all of the solutions but I can't figure out how mine isn't working.
I am building a custom theme for wordpress as part of a training course.
There is a page template called page-product.php.

The code for the img tag in the template is:

```
<img src='<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'product_large', true); ?>' />
```

The path for the image is:

D:\Programs\Xampp\htdocs\WidgetCorp\product-images\prod-sprocketizer-large.png

Here's a snapshot of the custom field I have made:
http://awesomescreenshot.com/0e51e0rs14

To prevent looping i have used:
`<?php the_post(); ?>` before i start writing the get_post_meta statements...

When I open the page I get a broken image icon.
What do I do?

I checked the source. The link is being echoed as

```
<img src= "/product-images/productname-size.png" />
```

but nothing before that.
so when i click on it, it says no object found.

Comment: check the src see what wordpress preprocesses with that code cause to me that code looks for a postID

Comment: Hey Matthias I did check the source.
The img tag did show up with the url and when I clicked on it it said object not found!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something you can try you have to edit it yourself check the output of the PHP

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/product-images/prod-sprocketizer-large.png" alt="new">
```

The bloginfo gives a relative path to your website i just fullwilled it with tha path to your url http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo

Comment: hey this worked! thanks a lot.
But the instructor used the code I was using earlier and his page worked just fine. Why is that so?

Comment: oh. but i have run into trouble with this code. in the category page i am unable to add the first part because the img tag is in an echo statement. what should i do now?

Answer (score 0):

Does this helps?

```
<?php if ( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'product_large', true ) ) : ?>

    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"">

        <img src="<?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'product_large', true ) ?>" />

    </a>

<?php endif; ?>
```

/Paul

Comment: My PHP is pretty basic, but I think the issue is in the **$post->ID** and **et_the_ID()**. Also must be inside the loop.

Comment: I didn't try this since the first reply worked. But thanks a lot for replying. I had used <?php get_header(); the_post(); ?> in the beginning though so that it does not loop.

Comment: dear kortschot,
the more complicated this part gets the more it becomes complicated on my category page :(
what is wrong with my code?
is get_post_meta no longer valid with wordpress? the instructor is using version 3.0 and i happen to download the latest...

Comment: jeee... would not know if it's supported prior 3.0. Information on this matter can be found in the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta). I'm on my phone now so might check tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you. Do check this tomorrow.
This is what I found on Codex:
USAGE: 
<?php $meta_values = get_post_meta($post_id, $key, $single); ?>
  DEFINITION: 


$post_id
(integer) (required) The ID of the post from which you want the data. Use get_the_ID() while in The Loop to get the post's ID, or use your sub-loop's post object ID property (eg $my_post_object->ID).

Comment: I am using option two: $my_post_object->ID

Comment: it's not the cleanest method but when your category.php worked before and you need continue on current work, make a category-**id**.php. Enter the ID of the category you are working in, ie. category-10.php. Slug is also good, category-products.php. More info [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates)

Comment: little side note, Advanced Custom Fields plugin makes your life a bit easier, google it. It's for adding custom meta boxes on posts, pages, types and such with a great uix.

Answer (score 0):

Your image is located at 'product-images' which is in your website.

therefore simply set the src of the image to as follows.

```
<img src='product-images/prod-sprocketizer-large.png' />
```

Comment: hi menuwordpress,
i can't do that because it is a template.
i need it to generate the image dynamically...

Comment: why don't you store only keep the url on the database. then you can do the same dynamically, without keep them on database. I think this is much faster!